# How to create an array without repetitions?

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array `s1` with values `[Alex, Jonh, Smith, Gomer, Bart, Peter, Bob]`.
The program creates a new array `s2` with values `[Jonh, Bart, null, null]`.

Can you suggest a method to add random values from `s1` to `s2`  without repetition?

**Example**:

First input: `s1 = [Jonh, Bart, Peter, Alex]`.
Second input: `s2 = [Jonh, Bart, Gomer, Smith]`.

Comment: Assuming you're not going for efficiency you could just check if the array already contains the name before adding it and if it does re-roll your random number

Comment: I need to add a random name from the array s1

Comment: And what difficulty have you experienced. Have you tried my low efficiency technique?

Comment: Maybe each time shuffle your array and pick its first `n` elements.

Comment: Pshemo, Good idea, I'll try it

Answer (score 0):

Use a queue's remove function. Not the most efficent way, but you don't have to write a single line of (real) logic

```
String[] names = new String[]{"Alex", "Jonh", "Smith", "Gomer", "Bart", "Peter", "Bob"};

//create list from your array
List<String> namesList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(names));

//shuffle list
Collections.shuffle(namesList);

//create queue with shuffeld content
Queue<String> shuffeldQueue = new ArrayDeque<String>(namesList);

//this will get and remove the queue's head i.e. it's first element (which a random element)
String randomName = shuffeldQueue.remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter out repeated elements after you have added them to the union of the two arrays, you can use [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php). Note that `array_unique` cannot work with multi dimensional arrays:

> Note that `array_unique()` is not intended to work on multi dimensional arrays.

If, differently, you intended to discard duplicate elements before they are added, then have a look at the [Set](http://php.net/manual/en/class.ds-set.php) class. There is only to note that PHP 7 is listed as a requirement in the [Requirements](http://php.net/manual/en/ds.requirements.php) page. If you haven't it installed, I suggest checking for a third-party library on the net.

A third and last solution would be checking manually the presence of possibly duplicate elements before they are added, but this is a solution which anyone would be perhaps able to reach.